# How can i automate unit test in VS 2013 using a test tool

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, tfs, mtm

Im new in testing and I have to find a software that will help us with automating testing that in the end we can do some regression testing.

We work with .NET and C# and we are using VS2013 and TFS 2010. I'm trying to find a software that we can link our Unit testing to the testcases and re use them.

I've been looking at Microsoft test manager and i found out i can't link the unit test that the developer have written to the work items and test it ? Is their any other software or is their a work around.

Answer (score 0):

You can link Unit Test to a test case work item in VS. Here are steps which are quoted from this MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx).

1. Check test project into TFS version control, and create one build definition for it.

[image]

2. Open test case work item in VS, click the ASSOCIATED AUTOMATION tab and select the test method you want.

[image]

Also have a check on this blog.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishp/archive/2011/04/06/how-to-associate-automation-for-test-cases-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: I've already seen that but i want to connect it in MTM ( microsoft test manager )

Comment: @Cosy, no, it is not allowed. To associate test method to a test case, you have to do it in Visual Studio.